# function clearInteraval not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a count Down timer which start automatically .
I would like to restart it when time finish with click on a button , actually in a certain time one of time or button is appear
problems : clearInteraval is not working , timeInteraval works in 500 not in 1000
Can anyone Help?
I hope you'll understand what I have said;

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        time : [0,0,4],
        date : new Date(),
        counterStop :false,  
    };
    // autoplay countdown counter
    this.startCounter();
}
```

this is main function of timer , I use setState in this function

```
    countdown = () =>{
        let hr = this.state.time[0];
        let mm = this.state.time[1];
        let ss = this.state.time[2];

            if(hr == 0 && mm == 0 && ss == 0 || mm<0){
                this.finishCounter();
                this.setState({counterStop:true})
            }

            ss--;
            if(ss < 0)
            {
                ss = 59;
                mm--;
                if(mm == 0)
                {
                    mm = 59;
                    hr--;
                }
            }
            
            if(hr.toString().length < 2) hr = "0"+hr;
            if(mm.toString().length < 2) mm = "0"+mm;
            if(ss.toString().length < 2) ss = "0"+ss;
            this.setState({
               time : [hr,mm,ss]
            })

    }
```

`clearInterval` not work here and I define time because state has changed in `countDown` timer

```
    finishCounter = () => {
        clearInterval(this.startCounter);
         this.setState({
            time : [0,0,4]
        })
        console.log('finishCounter')
    }

    startCounter =()=> {
        this.setState({time:[0,0,4],counterStop:false})
        setInterval(this.countdown, 1000) ;
    }
```

class component rendering

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>

            {
                this.state.counterStop 
                ? <button onClick={this.startCounter.bind(this)} >start counter</button>
                : <p>{`${this.state.time[0]} : ${this.state.time[1]} : ${this.state.time[2]}`}</p>
            }

            <button onClick={this.finishCounter.bind(this)}>stop</button>
        </div>        
    )
}
```

Comment: `clearInterval(this.startCounter);` that's not how you clear an interval. You have to store the return value of `setInterval` and pass it as argument to `clearInterval`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#example_2_alternating_two_colors

Answer (score 1):

To make @jabaa's suggestions into an explicit solution for your case of a React class component, try this:

```js
    finishCounter = () => {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.setState({
            time : [0,0,4]
        })
        console.log('finishCounter')
    }

    startCounter = () => {
        this.setState({time:[0,0,4],counterStop:false})
        this.interval = setInterval(this.countdown, 1000);
    }
```